# DLL_PROCESS_DETACH won't get called?

Tags: delphi, dll

A C# program calls a DLL which I have written in Delphi:

```
 [DllImport("ABCDEF.dll")]
 private static extern void OpenDrawer();
```

The DLL in Delphi has the function (among of other things) to open the drawer for an Epson POS printer.

Its DLLMain contains `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, which loads EpsStmApi.dll, and its `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` method frees EpsStmApi.dll again, as well as closes the printer handle, if one exists. The DLL-function OpenDrawer will call the DLL function and save the printer handle as global variable (this is important for the performance).

```
library Test;

var
  hEpsonDLL: cardinal = 0;  // DLL handle for EpsStmApi.dll
  hMonPrinter: integer = 0; // Printer handle. Stays open while the DLL is loaded, for performance

type
  TFuncBiOpenMonPrinter = function (nType: Integer; pName: LPSTR): Integer; stdcall;
  TFuncBiOpenDrawer = function (nHandle: Integer; drawer: Byte; pulse: Byte): Integer; stdcall;
  TFuncBiCloseMonPrinter = function (nHandle: Integer): Integer; stdcall;

var
  funcBiOpenMonPrinter : TFuncBiOpenMonPrinter;
  funcBiOpenDrawer : TFuncBiOpenDrawer;
  funcBiCloseMonPrinter : TFuncBiCloseMonPrinter;

procedure OpenDrawer; stdcall; export;
begin
  if hEpsonDLL <> 0 then
  begin
    // DLL missing. Probably no Epson printer installed.
    exit;
  end;
  if hMonPrinter = 0 then
  begin
    // Initialize the printer.
    @funcBiOpenMonPrinter := GetProcAddress(hEpsonDLL, 'BiOpenMonPrinter') ;
    if Assigned(funcBiOpenMonPrinter) then hMonPrinter := funcBiOpenMonPrinter(TYPE_PRINTER, 'EPSON TM-T88V Receipt');
  end;
  if hMonPrinter <> 0 then
  begin
    // Try to open the drawer
    @funcBiOpenDrawer := GetProcAddress(hEpsonDLL, 'BiOpenDrawer') ;
    if Assigned(funcBiOpenDrawer) then funcBiOpenDrawer(hMonPrinter, EPS_BI_DRAWER_1, EPS_BI_PULSE_400);
  end;
end;

procedure DllMain(reason: Integer);
begin
  if reason = DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH then
  begin
    // Note: Calling BiOpenMonPrinter here will cause a deadlock.
    hEpsonDLL := LoadLibrary('EpsStmApi.dll') ;
  end
  else if reason = DLL_PROCESS_DETACH then
  begin
    // Destroy the printer object
    if hMonPrinter <> 0 then
    begin
      @funcBiCloseMonPrinter := GetProcAddress(hEpsonDLL, 'BiCloseMonPrinter') ;
      if Assigned(funcBiCloseMonPrinter) then funcBiCloseMonPrinter(hMonPrinter);
    end;
    // Free the library
    if hEpsonDLL <> 0 then FreeLibrary(hEpsonDLL);
  end;
end;

exports
  OpenDrawer;

begin
  DllProc := DllMain;
  DllMain(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end.
```

It works so far, but I wonder if it is clean and correct, because I noticed that `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` will never be called (I checked it by writing to log files), therefore the printer handle stays open. I do not think it is a big deal, but I am unsure if something is not correct in-memory.
Is it possible that `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` does not get called because the DLL itself has another DLL loaded?

(Note: There is a reason why I don't call EpsStmApi.dll via C# directly, which is not relevant to this topic.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To begin with, what you report cannot be readily reproduced. A simple C# console application that calls a trivial Delphi DLL does indeed fire `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` when the process terminates.

```pascal
library Project1;

uses
  Windows;

procedure foo; stdcall;
begin
end;

procedure DllMain(reason: Integer);
begin
  if reason = DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH then begin
    OutputDebugString('DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH');
  end else if reason = DLL_PROCESS_DETACH then begin
    OutputDebugString('DLL_PROCESS_DETACH');
  end;
end;

exports
  foo;

begin
  DllProc := DllMain;
  DllMain(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH);
end.
```

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"Project1.dll")]
        static extern void foo();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly if this DLL is hosted in an executable that loads it with `LoadLibrary` and then unloads it with `FreeLibrary`, the `DllMain` call with reason `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` does fire. Most likely you are simply mistaken in your diagnosis.

If you wish to perform tasks when the DLL is loaded and unloaded, then perhaps a simpler way is to add code to a unit `initialization` and `finalization` sections. However, that code is still invoked from `DllMain` which severely limits what you can do, leading me to my next point.

You are breaking the rules for [`DllMain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dllmain). The documentation for `DllMain` says

> The entry-point function should perform only simple initialization or termination tasks. It must not call the LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx function (or a function that calls these functions), because this may create dependency loops in the DLL load order.

I guess you are getting away with this, at least for now. But things could easily change. Moving the code to `initialization` and `finalization` changes nothing because they are still invoked from `DllMain`.

I strongly advise you to remove all of your `DllMain` code. If you wish to delay load the DLL then do so using `delayed` or move the loading of the DLL into another exported function that performs initialisation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and detailed answer! Maybe the library  EpsStmApi had some issues with the wrong use of the DllMain functions (since I also had some weird deadlock issues). Now I understand that DllMain was wrongly used and so I have put the initialization and finalization stuff in separate exported functions, which are called by C# when the program starts, and when it ends (`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit`)